# Compare element values from different XML files and append to the 1st XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've the following 2 xml files and where i have to generate the XML exactly same as my Main XML File-1 by comparing the element values of **wd:Task_Name_ID** with  **TaskID** of XML File-2.

for example,
The Main XML File-1 **wd:Task_Name_ID** has the following values **Task-1,Task-2,Task-3,Task-4,Task-5**

And XML File-2 **TaskID** has **Task-2,Task-6,Task-7,Task-1**

Using **XSLT**,I need the file should be generated exactly same as **Main XML File-1** along with the **Task-6, Task-7**

**Main XML - File-1**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <wd:Get_Phase_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com" >
      <wd:Response_Data>
        <wd:Project>
          <wd:Project_Data>
            <wd:Project_ID>W-PROJECT-1</wd:Project_ID>
            <wd:Project_Name>W-PROJECT-1 Description</wd:Project_Name>
            <wd:Phase_Data>
              <wd:Task_Data>
                <wd:Task_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Task_Name_ID>Task-1</wd:Task_Name_ID>
                  <wd:Name>W-PHASE Task-1</wd:Name>
                </wd:Task_Name_Data>
              </wd:Task_Data>
              <wd:Task_Data>
                <wd:Task_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Task_Name_ID>Task-2</wd:Task_Name_ID>
                  <wd:Name>W-PHASE Task-2</wd:Name>
                </wd:Task_Name_Data>
              </wd:Task_Data>
              <wd:Task_Data>
                <wd:Task_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Task_Name_ID>Task-3</wd:Task_Name_ID>
                  <wd:Name>W-PHASE Task-3</wd:Name>
                </wd:Task_Name_Data>
              </wd:Task_Data>
              <wd:Task_Data>
                <wd:Task_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Task_Name_ID>Task-4</wd:Task_Name_ID>
                  <wd:Name>W-PHASE Task-4</wd:Name>
                </wd:Task_Name_Data>
              </wd:Task_Data>
              <wd:Task_Data>
                <wd:Task_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Task_Name_ID>Task-5</wd:Task_Name_ID>
                  <wd:Name>W-PHASE Task-5</wd:Name>
                </wd:Task_Name_Data>
              </wd:Task_Data>
            </wd:Phase_Data>
          </wd:Project_Data>
        </wd:Project>
      </wd:Response_Data>
    </wd:Get_Phase_Response>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**XML File-2**

```
<Report>
      <Details>
        <Project>W-PROJECT-1</Project>
        <TaskID>Task-2</TASKID>
        <Descr>W-PHASE Task-2</Descr>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <Project>W-PROJECT-1</Project>
        <TaskID>Task-6</TASKID>
        <Descr>W-PHASE Task-6</Descr>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <Project>W-PROJECT-1</Project>
        <TaskID>Task-7</TASKID>
        <Descr>W-PHASE Task-7</Descr>
      </Details>
      <Details>
        <Project>W-PROJECT-1</Project>
        <TaskID>Task-1</TASKID>
        <Descr>W-PHASE Task-1</Descr>
      </Details>
    </Report>
```

Comment: So, you want your output XML to be all of **Main XML File-1** *plus* the values from **XML File-2** that don't already exist in **Main XML File-1**?

Comment: You should be more explicit in what you want for output by showing the desired one. Do you want the namespaces? Or not? Does order matter? Or not?

Comment: Yes the output should be all of **Main XML File-1** Plus values from **XML File-2** that doesn't exist in **Main XML File-1**

Comment: I need the namespace but order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if the formatting comes out poorly, this is my first time answering a question. If you are using XSL 2.0 try the following method, using File-1 as input. You could expand this example to group Project_Data by Project_ID as well, but since you did not specify multiple Project_Data objects I did not include it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:variable name="details" select="doc('File-2.xml')"/>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="wd:Phase_Data">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Task_Data|$details/Report/Details" group-by="if(TaskID) then TaskID else wd:Task_Name_Data/wd:Task_Name_ID">
                    <xsl:element name="wd:Task_Data">
                        <xsl:element name="wd:Task_Name_Data">
                            <xsl:element name="wd:Task_Name_ID">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="wd:Name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="if(Descr) then Descr else wd:Task_Name_Data/wd:Name"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```